# sort list of lists using a specific variable from inner list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am doing some operations on file and converting its lines to a list

```
l1 = [
    ['john', 'age', '23', 'has', 'scored', '90,'],
    ['sam', 'scored', '70,', 'and', 'age', 'is', '19,'],
    ['rick', 'failed', 'as' ,'he', 'scored', '20,'],
]
```

As we see not all lists/lines are similar, but one thing will be common that is integer followed by word `'scored'`. 
Is there a way I can sort on the basis of integer which follows keyword `'scored'`?

Earlier I had tried with similar lists with following and it had worked but that wont help on above list

```
sorted(l1, key=lambda l: int(l[4].rstrip(',')),reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>>> a_list = [['john', 'age', '23', 'has', 'scored', '90,'], 
['sam', 'scored', '70,', 'and', 'age', 'is', '19,'], 
['rick', 'failed', 'as', 'he', 'scored', '20,']]

>>> sorted(a_list, key = lambda l: int(l[l.index('scored') + 1].strip(",")), reverse=True)

[['john', 'age', '23', 'has', 'scored', '90,'], 
 ['sam', 'scored', '70,', 'and', 'age', 'is', '19,'], 
 ['rick', 'failed', 'as', 'he', 'scored', '20,']]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help !

Comment: Can we give some parameter in above code to just give top 10 among the sorted list ?

Comment: You could just slice the sorted list for the top 10

Comment: got it , just needed to add [:10] at the end of above code